Azure IOT Hub device update agent for windows or any supporting libraries in c#
I am trying to build one application to get the update package Msi file from azure IOT hub to device using device updater service I found one package azure.iot.devices where I can import updates and monitor it but I didn’t get the simulator code how can I get the update package files in device …need help or some inputs how I can achieve this.

could please tell me what your requirement?

Use the DeviceClient class from the Microsoft.Azure.Devices namespace to connect to your IoT Hub.

@Sampath I need to create updater agent which runs in windows and get the updater file once deployment starts

Device Update for Azure IoT Hub using the Ubuntu (18.04 x64) simulator reference agent. For  Device Update for Azure IoT Hub using the package agent on Ubuntu Server 18.04 x64. if you are using Windows refer to How to install Ubuntu 18.04 on Windows 10


I followed this doc and trying to implement it.



Using resources provided by Ms-Doc and Ms-Doc1, I successfully imported a new update into IoT Hub.

using  Azure.IoT.DeviceUpdate package we can work with the updater agent in c#.

Azure Device Update for IoT Hub client library for .NET 

Refer  this git  of using Azure.IoT.DeviceUpdate with C#.

Using  REST API for  Azure Device Update. you use rest api  with c# as well.




To add Access Control in IoT Hub, navigate to your IoT Hub in the Azure portal, select Access Control (IAM) from the navigation menu, and then choose 'Add role assignment'.




Ensure that the IoT Hub Data Contributor role appears under Role Assignments after selecting Azure Device Update.

To search for "Azure Device Update," use the selection options for User, Group, or Service Principal.





Select 'Devices' from the left pane, then choose 'Add Device'.

Select 'Add Module Identity', and then enter a name for the module in the 'Module Identity Name' field.

In the twin file, alongside the model ID and version tags, insert a new tag for Device Update with the following value:


"tags": {
    "ADUGroup": "DU-simulator-tutorial"
},




To Install and configure the Device Update agent



Choose the 'Upload' option in your container, then proceed to the files required. After selecting the adu-update-image-raspberrypi3.swu and TutorialImportManifest_Sim.importmanifest.json files, click on 'Upload' to proceed.

After selecting "Check the Status" in Groups and Deployments.




Thank you @Sampath for providing the step-by-step instructions. Just to be clear, unless we run the update agent on Ubuntu, the group and deployment won't appear?Alternatively, if we simply add the twin, the groups will appear under deployments. I followed the instructions exactly, but I still can't see any groups under deployments.

check Monitor the update deployment add Remotely collect diagnostic logs from devices using Device Update for IoT Hub

is there any connection between running update agent and deployments and groups or with out any update agent does the groups get appear?

yes, there is a connection between running the update agent and seeing deployments and groups in Azure Device Update. Without the update agent running, your device cannot communicate its group affiliation to the service.

thank you so much for taking time and answering my queries will check with my PO and will try to implement

so we don't have simulator for windows if we want to run updater agent on windows with out ubuntu is it possible. I mean we have to run updater agent on windows without ubuntu. @Sampath

Not possible. We use wsl as intermediate to use windows as ubuntu
